# Can someone please explain Android BatteryManger parameters

Tags: android, battery, batterymanager

I am confused about the Battery Manager Parameters. can someone please explain below points:

BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER -

> Battery capacity in microampere-hours, as an integer.

Ques - Is it the remaining battery capacity or total battery Capacity.
If its total , why does it change
If its remaining( when i charged my phone 100% ) the values were somethign like 3366079 but total capcity of my phone's battery is 3300 mAh( read from power profile )
How can this be greater than 3300 mAh ?

```
Integer chargeCounter = mBatteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER);
Integer capacity = mBatteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
Long energyCounter = mBatteryManager.getLongProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER);
```

long batteryCapacity = (chargeCounter/capacity) *100;

logs are as foolow :

> Charge Counter: 3366079 
>   capacity 100 
>   Battery Capacity is :3366000

BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER

> Battery remaining energy in nanowatt-hours, as a long integer.

This parameter returns 0 ( tested on 2 devices )
Ques - Should this value be the remaining battery capacity value off 3300 mAH? or else what does this mean ?

Devices Used - LG G6 and Pixel 1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of physics behind these questions, for the first one,
How can this be greater than 3300 mAh ?
When manufacturers make a new battery they make them using a range, if your battery says it is 3300mAh there will be a range of error of +/- some error percentage.
Also to measure the battery they use a sensor which is prone to certain percentage of error too.
All these measures are converted from analog to digital which also conducts to another error.
I think this link could help: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/device

For your second question, check this post:
[Android BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER returning fixed value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188691/android-battery-property-energy-counter-returning-fixed-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: The reason I am intrested in this is because of one App name "Accubatery " They have this "Batery Health" in which they calculate, health based on Design Capacity Vs Estimated Capacity. So i am intrested in getting estimated capacity of my battery